# Auto connecting to PDO only if needed

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have a section of code that depending on the URL requested, will include one of fourteen other files.  Some of these fourteen files require a connection to one of three different databases, and additional files can be added at anytime.

I don't want to open PDO connections by default to all three database as its a waste of resources and will slow the execution time down.  So my thought is to wrap all SQL queries within a function.  The first time that a query is executed on a non-open PDO connection, the try {} error handler can catch it, find out what the problem was (in this case connection doesnt exist), then open the connection and re-execute the query.  That way, the database is only being connected to as and when needed - as long as the connection string (host, database, username, password) are all defined in advance, I can't see any problem in it working.

However, I need to push on with this, and don't have access to the dev box for about 7 days, so can anyone see any problem with that scenario?  Also, can anyone give me the error message that handler->errorInfo() will return if the connection isn't opened?

Comment: I'd suggest telling PDO to throw exceptions on error rather than rely on `errorInfo`. In the connection options, use `array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`

Comment: @Chris, depends. If application in general does not use exceptions, enabling them in PDO will do more harm than good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the right idea, but not the best implementation of it.

Wrapping the SQL operations is good. But why don't you do it this way:

```
class Wrapper {
    private static $db;

    public static function someQuery() {
        $db = self::getDatabase();
        // now go on to execute the query
    }

    private static function getDatabase() {
        if (self::$db === null) {
            self::$db = // connect here
        }
        return self::$db;
    }
}
```

This has a lot of advantages:

- Allows you to logically group SQL operations into one (or several!) classes
- Does not connect to database if not needed
- Does not depend on (brittle) error checks to function correctly

In your specific case, you should probably go with 3 separate `Wrapper` classes. Putting everything into one class is doable (three different `$db` variables) but probably more confusing than it's worth.

Comment: Hi guys, wow - didn't expect an answer so quickly!! Chris/Jon, thanks very much for your answers.  

I'm presuming you can't use Variable variables with PDO?  My thought was to pass the Database name with the query, and then get the code to deal with the connection as appropriate - as long as the connection strings are predefined.  That would then avoid three separate wrapper classes - but I don't think that will work ... will it?

Comment: thanks for your example, I think thats the way I'll go forward.  Must also say thanks - i've never understood private functions before ... your example showed me how they can be used!

Comment: @TIW, about private members - there are also protected members ;) While private members can be used only in class where they are defined, protected members can also be used in child classes, i.e., in classes that extend a class where protected member is defined.

Answer (score 13):

Use this class exactly how you would use the `PDO` class.

```
class DB extends PDO {

    protected $_config = array();

    protected $_connected = false;

    public function __construct($dsn, $user = null, $pass = null, $options = null) {
        //Save connection details for later
        $this->_config = array(
            'dsn' => $dsn,
            'user' => $user,
            'pass' => $pass,
            'options' => $options
        );
    }

    public function checkConnection() {
        if (!$this->_connected) {
            extract($this->_config);
            parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $pass, $options)
            $this->_connected = true;
        }
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $this->checkConnection();
        return parent::query($query);
    }

    public function exec($query) {
        $this->checkConnection();
        return parent::exec($query);
    }

    //etc.
}
```

Comment: Best way to do it. PDO is meant to be extended.

Comment: You would return the results of the overloaded methods of course. Other than that; sound answer!

Comment: Hi guys, wow - didn't expect an answer so quickly!! Chris/Jon, thanks very much for your answers.  

This may be me, being thick - no comments please! - but with Chris' answer, I can't see how it could decide which of the three databases to connect to? Or am i missing something.  PDO is very new to me, but seems logical!

Comment: I find it more comfortable to write a wrapper that does not directly extend PDO, but uses it as a parameter of an object (i.e., `$this->db = new PDO()`). That way, I can (1) write easier-to-use interface for interacting with DB and (2) can change DB extension from PDO to something else and keep using my wrapper without any problems, if I ever need it.

Comment: @TIW, you would have 3 objects (e.g., `$db1`, `$db2` and `$db3`), each of which is created with different arguments (host, port, user, pswd).

Comment: Hi All, thanks for that.  @binaryLV if its done as a wrapper, what type would you define 'db' as ... ie the $this->db.

Comment: @TIW, as PDO. Additionally, there might be private or protected getter for it, something like `protected function getDb() { if ( is_null($this->db) ) { $this->initDB(); } return $this->db; }`. This getter would have to be used in class methods `select()`, `exec()` methods etc (instead of using `$this->db`).

Answer (score 5):

I took another approach using __call magic method so you don't need to create individual wrappers for every method.

```
class PDOLazyConnector
{
    private $dsn;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $driver_options;
    private $dbh;

    public function __construct ($dsn, $username, $password, $driver_options = array ())
    {
        $this->dsn = $dsn;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->driver_options = $driver_options;
    }

    public function __call ($function, $args)
    {
        // connect to db (first time only)
        $this->__init_dbh ();

        // invoke the original method
        return call_user_func_array (array($this->dbh, $function), $args);
    }

    public function __get ($property)
    {
        return $this->dbh->$property;
    }

    private function __init_dbh ()
    {
        // If db handler is not open yet, do it now
        if (empty ($this->dbh)) {
            $this->dbh = new PDO ($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password, $this->driver_options);
        }
    }       
}
```

You just have to replace your PDO instancing with PDOLazyConnector, so:

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $driver_options);
```

with:

```
$dbh = new PDOLazyConnector($dsn, $user, $password, $driver_options);
```

Answer (score 1):

PDO has an option for persistent connections **PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT**.

See the comments in http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function &get_pdo()
{
    static $_PDO = null;

    if ($_PDO === null)
    {
        $_PDO = new PDO('your DSN', 'username', 'password');
    }

    return $_PDO;
}
```

Then you just do

```
$stmt = get_pdo()->prepare('...');
```

You could do the same by extending the PDO class and adding a static singleton function to it. I find this approach simplier. Also gives you the opportunity to call it from anywhere on the stack without having to put your connection in the arguments (which can be good or bad, depending on the situation).