# How to detain PDO from establishing a connection until the first query?

Tags: php, pdo

I am establishing a connection to the database upon every script execution. It is done by assigning a PDO instance to a global `$db` variable that is then passed to the controller.

```
$db = new \ay\pdo\PDO('mysql:dbname=foo;charset=utf8');
```

However, because there is a cache-logic layer, 95% requests do not need to execute a single query. While 5ms to establish a connection might not seem significant, it is 30% of the request time. When serving up to 200K requests a minute, this is a significant number.

[image: app]

I would like to establish a connection to the database only when there is a query to execute. What is the recommended way of achieving this without putting a significant overhead on the script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484790/auto-connecting-to-pdo-only-if-needed

Comment: Ah! Failed to find it! This answer seem to confirm the validity of my approach, http://stackoverflow.com/a/5484811/368691.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may/can use proxy design pattern. So it will handle/create connection to db when you first time ask for data.

So instead using PDO directly you create proxy object, when there is query it creates connection to db, and query it (lazy loading), then later on it would reuse the same PDO object.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern

Proxy example: https://github.com/ezimuel/PHP-design-patterns/blob/master/Proxy.php

Comment: How does this compare to https://github.com/gajus/pdo/blob/master/deferred/pdo.class.php ?

Comment: what is inside \ay\pdo\PDO ?

Comment: Answering to your first question you are extending class (is a)  relationship while in proxy you have composition (has a) so you are not creating nothing until you need.

Comment: Both approaches achieve the same result. The main Proxy/Flyweight pattern disadvantage compared to extending the original class is that your proxy will need to provide a hook for every method. Maybe it could be reworked, e.g. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/640c976f67eb103a0f32. Though, I prefer extending the original class and not executing the parent constructor until such is needed.

Comment: Yes achieve the same, you haven't provided example at the beginning. So in your case is it still creates connection? or it's just architecture decision you want to make? Overall i would go for composition way instead creating inheritance tree.

Comment: If you are referring to https://github.com/gajus/pdo/blob/master/deferred/pdo.class.php, then no, it will not create a connection until such is required. I plan to reuse this approach on other projects as well, therefore my preference is inheritance. Nevertheless, thank you for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using $db->method, use db()->method. db() would be a function or function in an pbject that returns a singleton db object / if connection exists, return that, else create it and return it.

Edit: Referring to the comments, perhaps singleton or global functions were not what you were looking for. what I was getting at was anyway that you could create an object $db that had all the connection params, but didn't create the connection. Then you could call something like

```
$db->getDb()->method
```

and getDb() would first check if $db has a connection, if not. then it creates it. you would have to have the getDb() before each call, or then internally in the $db object.

Comment: Apart from the overhead of calling a global function, this encourages use of singleton pattern. The latter is if anything, then a good indicator of a poor code design (stateful flow).

Comment: You are right about it being an indicator. But while it might be an a bad descision, it is a falacy to think that 'indicator of poor design' is an actual argument. It does fix your problem, and in this case I see no big issues. Unless you can come up with an actual reason this will be bad, I'd seriously consider it.

Comment: @Nanne I had to help a colleague less than a month ago to debug a code that was using singleton-ish approach to refer to the database connection. It became a problem when he tried to instantiate another PDO instance for a different database. The fact that I had to help him to refactor the code and he wasn't able to track-down the issues himself, shows that it is both: a hard pattern to oversee potential issues in the future and a poor pattern when it comes down to debugging.

Comment: @Nanne, regarding your updated answer, it sounds like this is the approach that you have described. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/640c976f67eb103a0f32

Comment: @GajusKuizinas I don't know, I didn't provide an answer, just that comment :). Anyway, if you do it bad and/or don't plan ahead every pattern can be abused, but that is still no actual reason why it wouldn't work in this case.