# How to find all object instances?

Tags: php

```
class Bar {
    public function defer () {
        // Here, I want to replace all instances of $foo with new Baz instance.
    };
}

class Baz {
    public function test () {
        echo 'Test';
    }
}

$foo = new Bar();

$foo->defer();

$foo->test();
```

Is there a way to find all instances of the current object and replace it with another? This is effectively eq. to overloading instance `$this` variable.

Refer to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21092438/368691 for an implementation limited to the $GLOBALS scope.

Comment: What happens if you do `$this = new Baz();` ?

Comment: You will get "Cannot re-assign $this" error. I know this limitation. Therefore, I am thinking if this can be addressed the other way around, e.g. by overwriting all existing instances.

Comment: Why do such thing? What do you mean under "all instances"? All - where? Whole program? Current scope? Or what?

Comment: I suppose it is fair to explain the intention. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121377/how-to-detain-pdo-from-establishing-a-connection-until-the-first-query and https://github.com/gajus/pdo/blob/psr-autoloader/src/gajus/oodo/deferred/pdo.php. Essentially, I want to overwrite the PDO object after the first query to avoid the overhead of checking if the connection has been already established.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas `Essentially, I want to overwrite the PDO object after the first query to avoid the overhead of checking if the connection has been already established` You are doing something completely wrong.If the connection isn't established, the PDO object wouldn't even exist because the constructor establishes the connection

Answer (score 0):

I needed some time to get what you are trying to do. What you are trying defeats the principles of good programming, especially responsibility concerns.

Why should one component change the data type of already created variables, without the code that created the variables knows about??

Comment: You are probably getting to using `__call` and other magic methods, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: if not, then you have misunderstood the question. See my answer as an example, though incomplete.

Comment: @hek2mgl: is there a specific reason for checking if `$instances` is array in constructor?

Comment: @Glavić Yeah, otherwise the push operation would trigger an error because `$instances` isn't an array. You should always take care on initializing your variables properly.

Comment: I know, but why didn't you just initialize it in property declaration? Like `protected static $instances = [];` ?

Comment: Can (here) be done as well. However inline initializing class members in the class definition has some restrictions in PHP. So I decided to use the most compat way

Answer (score 0):

If the assumption was that the variable can be only in the global scope, then the solution is fairly simple:

```
<?php
class Bar {
    public function defer () {
        array_walk_recursive($GLOBALS, function (&$e) {
            if ($e instanceof $this) {
                $e = new Baz();
            }
        });
    }
}

class Baz {}

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->defer();

var_dump( $bar );
```

Which will produce:

```
object(Baz)#4 (0) {
}
```

However, this answer is more of a guidance looking for the final answer, rather than a definitive solution.

Example application:

```
<?php
class PDODeferred extends \PDO {
    private
        $constructor,
        $attributes = [];

    public function __construct ($dsn, $username = null, $password = null, array $driver_options = []) {
        $this->constructor = [$dsn, $username, $password, $driver_options];
    }

    public function exec ($statement) {
        $db = $this->connect();

        return $db->exec($statement);
    }

    public function setAttribute ($attribute, $value) {
        $this->attribute[$attribute] = $value;
    }

    private function connect () {
        $db = new \PDO($this->constructor[0], $this->constructor[1], $this->constructor[2], $this->constructor[3]);

        foreach ($this->attributes as $attribute => $value) {
            $db->setAttribute($attribute, $value);
        }

        array_walk_recursive($GLOBALS, function (&$e) use ($db) {
            if ($e instanceof $this) {
                $e = $db;
            }
        });

        return $db;
    }
}

$db = new PDODeferred('mysql:dbname=foo');

// No connection is made to the DB yet.

$db->exec("SELECT 1;");

// Connection is made.

$db->exec("SELECT 1");

// $db is now regular PDO instance.
```

Comment: Why don't you update your question with your findings, and not add them as answers???

Comment: @Glavić because this is already a partial solution and might be the answer to those who stumble upon the question.

Comment: Still, IMHO you should add this to the question, since new people that will come to see this question will have better understanding of what you want, instead of looking what you found out in the answers...

Comment: Sure. Added reference.