# Declaration of x::prepare() should be compatible with PDO::prepare

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Since I make connections to an external database, I need a way that the connection to the database is done only if it's necessary (if there's a query).

I found this answer on StackOverflow: [Auto connecting to PDO only if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5484811/4856683)

It's perfect and I adopt this method. I think it's a clean way to do it. But here's the problem:

Almost always I use prepared statements for my queries, example:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username");
$sth->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

But using prepared statements with the class of the above answer it gives me:

> **Warning**: PDO::prepare(): SQLSTATE[00000]: No error: PDO constructor was not called
>
> **Fatal Error**: Call to a member function bindParam() on null

So I added in the class:

```
public function prepare($query)
{
    $this->checkConnection();
    return parent::prepare($query);
}
```

And it works. But it gives me always this warning:

> **Strict Standards**: Declaration of DB::prepare() should be compatible with PDO::prepare($statement, $options = NULL) in class_pdo.php on line 0

Does anyone know why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `PDO::prepare` can take a second argument, like it says in the error message. Since your class is a subclass of PDO, it can't drop support for something that the PDO base class supported.

Thankfully, it's easy to fix:

```
public function prepare($query, $options = NULL) # <-- add the argument
{
    $this->checkConnection();
    return parent::prepare($query, $options);    # <-- and pass it on
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, Just one thing that I notice now. With NULL it gives me `PDO::prepare() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given`. So instead of NULL I've inserted an empty array and it works.